# filename missing from upload when Uploading to Google Cloud Storage from Wordpress on Google App Engine PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, google-app-engine

I have my GCS bucket set up in Wordpress/GAE PHP, I go into the wordpress admin and click on a post and attempt to upload a file.  The file looks like it is uploading fine, but then when it finishes it says HTTP error.  When I look at the logs on GAE, I see it says

PHP Fatal error:  Google Cloud Storage filename missing from upload in Unknown on line 0

Any ideas on what might be causing this?

UPDATE/EDIT: This is resolved

In the plugin settings it says

Leave blank to use the default bucket

I assumed the default bucket was whatever bucket I had created - if there was only one I assumed it would use that bucket.  That was not the case, so I had to enter the bucket name (the first time I got this it generated an error, so I assumed that was not the answer)